# Decompiling APK to find how it checks for root

Tags: android

So i have an android app (payqwiq) which has root detection. Using magisk i have managed to get my phone to pass safetynet and i can use android pay, however this payqwiq app still throws an error.

I was recommended in the magisk support thread to decompile the apk and check for dependencies and if it is checking for props and told to Google it.

So i used apktools to decompile the apk and poured over the smali files. I found a method in LaunchActivity.smali that looked promising but i cannot for the life of me figure out what it is actually checking for.

Please could i have some help with what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) to decompile the classes.dex file within an APK file to Java.